# Wrong result by using $sscanf in systemVerilog

Tags: string, system-verilog

I have the following string:

```
str= "w, 0, A0002000, 00000000, \n"
```

I use (mode is declare as a bit, len as int' and ax_trx as bit [31:0]):

```
$sscanf(str, "%c", mode);
$sscanf(str, "%d", len);      
$sscanf(str,"%h", ax_trx.addr)
```

For some reason the results I got are:
mode is '1' (I expected it to be 'w').
len is 00000000 (I'm not sure if it's ok).
ax_trx.addr is 00000000 (I expected it to be A0002000).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot expect to have signal declared as bit with value 'w', bit can have only  0 or 1 value.

According to System Verilog specification (chapter 21.3.4.3):

`If an argument is too small to hold the converted input, then, in general, the LSBs are transferred`

Comment: what about %h? it shoul hold A0002000 rigt?

Comment: I think that you misunderstood how sscanf function works. First I encourage you to read chapter 21.2.4.3 of SystemVerilog specification, you can get here: http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf

Comment: `**$sscanf** has three arguments: 
**str** - string from which you want to read, 
**format** - control string that describes format of given str string,
**args** - args are variables that will store values read from string.

Problem with your code is that you want to get character from string and store it in bit variable. When you change format to %h then $sscanf will try to find first HEX and store it in bit.

I'v created simple testbench, you can see how $sscanf works:
[https://www.edaplayground.com/x/37iR](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/37iR)

Comment: When you call `$sscanf(str, "%c", mode);` then simulator is looking for character in str starting from beginning, it will find 'w' which  has ASCII code 77(hex) and will store this value(77) in mode variable, mode is only 1bit, so mode will have value 1 (least significant bit of value 0x77). You have to extend mode to at least 8 bits so it can store whole ASCII code of character. Watch out for multiple calls to $sscanf, each call will start from first character of string. If you want to read multiple values from one string then do it in single call to $sscanf(), like in example from prev comm

Comment: I changed the code to $sscanf(str, "%c %d %h", mode, len, ax_trx.addr);, still got wrong results in len (00000000), and ax_trx.addr (00000000)

Comment: you get wrong results because you are trying to read "," as decimal value, in your str first character is 'w', another is ',' and it cannot be read as decimal value. $sscanf return number of succesfully matched and assigned input items, always check if it equals to your number of args.

Comment: so how can I execute what I need?

Comment: Have you read specification ? You expect me to give you working code but I rather encourage you to do it on your own. I'll give you one more tip: to read len value you have to read all characters that are before len, those characters are: 'w' and ',', all commas in your string need to be included in your $sscanf format.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example: (%c for single character, %s for string, %d for decimal, %h for hex, see format [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm))

```
module test;

  initial begin
    string str = "w, 10, A0002000, deadbeef, \n";
    string mode = "";
    int len = 0;
    bit [31:0] address = 0;
    int data = 0;

    $display("mode (%s) len (%d) address (%h) data (%h)", mode, len, address, data);
    $sscanf(str, "%c, %d, %h, %h,", mode, len, address, data);
    $display("mode (%s) len (%d) address (%h) data (%h)", mode, len, address, data);

  end
endmodule
```

which produces:

```
mode () len (          0) address (00000000) data (00000000)
mode (w) len (         10) address (a0002000) data (deadbeef)
```